# Editing an email, AMPScript does not stay in the spot I put it in after saving the email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, content-builder

I am having a weird, serious issue.  I have an email with basic content.  See screenshot - basically, the intent is to wrap if/endif around these content blocks to show the appropriate block.  I've done this TONS of times before.  Notice "Elevate", "HDHP", etc.?  These will be wrapped in if/endif AMPScript.

[image]

However, when I do this:
[image]

And then save the email, ALL the if/endif logic gets pushed to the top, like this:
[image]

My expectation is that when putting AMPScript in certain areas of the email, that AMPScript should STAY in that location after saving.  What's going on???

Comment: Yeah, it's supposed to stay put. I would create a new email from scratch, and then copy/paste the HTML in it. Assuming that the issue won't happen in the newly created email. If it does, however, then I would open a help ticket.

Comment: @Harley yeah, I did that, same issue even on an email built from scratch (no template).  Just straight copy pasted HTML.  I've NEVER had this problem before.  Weird.  Support ticket opened.

Comment: are you using a free form block?

Comment: @EazyE HTML block

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping each of your Ampscript in HTML comments. For example, replacing:

`%%[ your ampscript ]%%`

with

`<!-- %%[ your ampscript ]%% -->`

Generally this keeps it in place better. The SFMC WYSIWYG editor can do some strange stuff at times. It's not clear where you are doing the editing here, but in my experience using the 'free form' content block type tends to do the least amount of manipulation, whereas using Content Builder for CloudPages seems to add/move stuff around quite a bit.